# Hide/Show TabBar in ViewController loops

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

**Situation**:

I have a few `ViewControllers` (all with a `NavigationBar`) embedded in a `TabBarController`. I have one specific `ViewController` (**VC1**) where I don't want to show the `TabBar`. From there you can go to another specific `ViewController` (**VC2**), where the `TabBar` needs to be shown again.

**My solution**:

**VC1**

`self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` is set to `true` by default

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {      
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

**VC2**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {      
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
}
```

So far so good. This seems to be working, but you can push another **VC1** from **VC2** (Same controller with different content) and of course push another **VC2** from **VC1** again and so on.

**The Problem**:

1. As soon as **VC2** is pushed twice from a **VC1** the `TabBar` is always hidden.
2. When you hit the back button to go from a **VC1** back to a **VC2** the `TabBar` is always hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize only VC1

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
}
```

It is simpler architecture

Comment: This is working fine, however the TabBar is now displayed without sliding in from left resp. right. Is there an easy way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Do not put the logic in `viewWillDisappear` or `prepareForSegue` since you do not know what kind of behavior the view controller that is about to be presented wants. Put the logic inside `viewWillAppear` instead.

Let every ViewController handle its own desired behavior and do not try to anticipate what the destination wants. Especially because you do not always know what the reason for `viewWillDisappear` or `prepareForSegue` is - therefore you cannot react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try change property in needed VC:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these code in viewWillApear for hide or unhide , it'll work fine .

For VC1 : - In this you want always hide then add this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
}
```

For VC2 : - In this you want always show then add this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
}
```

[image]
Try this code , Its working fine . I also tried this code in sample project.